# Installation error in django with using pip

Tags: python, django, windows, pip

I'm new to the Django world and I want to install it from pip into my windows but I get this error when installing:

```
C:\Users\xxxx>pip install django
Collecting django
**Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Could not find a suitable
 TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: \ms4w\Apache\conf\ca-bundle\cacert.pem**
```

The version of pip that i use is:

```
pip 10.0.1 from c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

Comment: What does `python -c "import certifi; print(certifi.where())"` output?

Comment: I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'certifi' and i tried to install pip install certifi  i get Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Could not find a suitable
 TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: \ms4w\Apache\conf\ca-bundle\cacert.pem

Comment: You can download the `certifi` wheel, then install it from FS: go to [`package page on PyPI`](https://pypi.org/project/certifi/#files), download the wheel, then run `pip install C:\path\to/cerifit.whl`.

Comment: Many thanks,i installed the same as you said and re-entered the 'python -c "import certifi; print(certifi.where())" '  and its output is as follows:C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem

Comment: Is this finally resolved?