# Pip install TLS CA issue

Tags: python, macos, pip, certificate

Every time I try to pip install something, this happens:

```
Lucianos-Mac:test luciano$ pip install torch
Collecting torch
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: /Users/luciano/Applications/NextGIS/Library/Frameworks/openssl.framework/Resources/ssl/certs/cert.pem
```

The path it references was created when I installed the gdal package from nextgis.com, which I later deleted, so the NextGIS directory does not exist. However, pip still looks there for a certificate and I don't know how to change this. I'm using Python 3.6 with Pip 19.0.3 on MacOS 10.14.

EDIT: `env | grep cert` outputs

```
SSL_CERT_FILE=/Users/luciano/Applications/NextGIS/Library/Frameworks/openssl.framework/Resources/ssl/certs/cert.pem
CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/Users/luciano/Applications/NextGIS/Library/Frameworks/openssl.framework/Resources/ssl/certs/cert.pem
```

unsetting these temporarily solve the problem, but when I restart the terminal, they are set again, and I don't know where.

Comment: See the commenst at https://stackoverflow.com/q/52880672/7976758

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Could+not+install+packages+due+to+an+EnvironmentError+Could+not+find+a+suitable+TLS+CA+certificate+bundle

Comment: This didn't work, when I type `python -c "import certifi; print(certifi.where())"`, I get `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem`. I tried reinstalling but nothing changed.

Comment: I also looked at the other post, but there's no `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` variable in my environment.

Comment: Maybe check to see if they are set in your `~/.bash_profile`...

Comment: *unsetting these temporarily solve the problem, but when I restart the terminal, they are set again* In your `~/.bash_profile`? `~/.bashrc`? In global bash settings?

Comment: I've checked all those places but I don't see those variables being defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete (or edit) these two files:

```
/Users/<user>/Library/LaunchAgents/setenv.CURL_CA_BUNDLE.plist
/Users/<user>/Library/LaunchAgents/setenv.SSL_CERT_FILE.plist
```

In the same folder NextGIS puts three other files that are setting ENV variables. I think they also should be taken care of.

Answer (score 1):

You can trace the environment variable to wherever it gets set by:

```
$ PS4='+$BASH_SOURCE> ' BASH_XTRACEFD=7 bash -xl 2> ~/desktop/trace.log ; reset
```

> Followed by <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

Then issue the following command:

```
$ grep REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE ~/desktop/trace.log
```

It should return the location of where it's getting set within your environment.

Comment: I tried this but those variables don't appear in the file. When I echo the variables they exist, but they are not in that file.

Comment: @Luciano: In that case try the following command `sudo find / -type f -exec grep -H -n "REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE" {} \;`. That should search your entire system for the location of where that variable might be set.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after a failed attempt to install Docker. The process did have something to do with ca-certificates. So I install the package with

> sudo apt install ca-certificates

and voila, things get back to normal again.
Hope this help.