# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path

Tags: python, ssl, pip

I get this error:

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: /home/yosra/Desktop/CERT.RSA

When I run: `$ virtualenv venv`

So I put a random CERT.RSA on the Desktop which worked and I created my virtual environment, but then when I run: `pip install -r requirements.txt`

I got this one:

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /KristianOellegaard/django-hvad/archive/2.0.0-beta.tar.gz (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(0, 'unknown error (_ssl.c:3715)'),))

I feel that these 2 errors are linked to each other, but I want to know how can I fix the first one?

Comment: See the comments at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52880672/installation-error-in-django-with-using-pip#comment92675198_52880672

Comment: @phd It didn't help, when I try to install `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/certifi/cacert.pem` I get the same old error: `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: /home/yosra/Desktop/CERT.RSA`

Answer (score 27):

If you're on Mac (mine is 10.13.6), use the following command:

```
(security find-certificate -a -p ls /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain &&        security find-certificate -a -p ls /Library/Keychains/System.keychain) > $HOME/.mac-ca-roots
```

Then do modify `.bashrc` with

```
export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE="$HOME/.mac-ca-roots"
```

Then do

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Doesn't works for me (Mac 10.14.6). if it does for you, could you explain what this command does ?

Comment: @AnumSheraz There is a missing step  and I modified answer. Can you try again to see if it helps? The error it fixed is `SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)`.

Comment: Tried this but my user doesn't have ".bashrc" so I cannot fix it using this method now.

Comment: works for me. I have macos 11.5.2

Comment: @MatthewHarris any shell profile should work as well.

Answer (score 12):

In Windows 10, 
1. Find the location of certifi with following commands to check if installed already

```
import certifi
certifi.where()
```

2. Note down the path of cacert.pem file
3. Search for the pip.ini file in windows explorer and edit the file in notepad and set the `path = <file path of cacert.pem >`

Comment: Find all the possible `pip.ini` files by running the command `pip config -v list`

Comment: Getting no module named certifi error :)

Answer (score 11):

You need to allow pip to reference to the correct certificate. check the certificate first;

```
python -c "import certifi; print(certifi.where())"
```

Then first test it manually;

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --cert=<the above certificate path>
```

If that works fine, then update this path on pip.conf file located at $HOME/.pip/pip.conf (or %APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini on Windows). e.g.

```
[global]
cert = /usr/local/share/ca-certificate/mycert.crt
```

Answer (score 6):

Fix for Windows 10,

Error faced: `error: could not install packages due to an oserror: could not find a suitable tls ca certificate bundle, invalid path: c:\program files\postgresql\16\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt` . Encountered during installing new packages using pip.

Reason: postgresql installation somehow updated the system environment Variable.

Fix in two steps(worked for me):

1. Update the system environment `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` variable with
   `cacert.pem` path present in
   `Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\certifi\cacert.pem`.
   Note add the full path, in my case `C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\certifi\cacert.pem`
2. Restart the pc

Answer (score 5):

I received this error while running the command as "pip install flask" in Pycharm.

If you look at the error, you will see that the error points out to "`packages due to an EnvironmentError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle -- Invalid path`".

I solved this by removing the environment variable "`REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE`" OR you can just change the name of the environment variable "`REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE`" to some other name.

Restart your Pycharm and this should be solved.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Old post. But answering for my future self and anyone else who gets stuck at this!

First locate the pip.conf(linux):

```
[root@localhost ~]# pip3 config -v list
For variant 'global', will try loading '/etc/xdg/pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'global', will try loading '/etc/pip.conf'
For variant 'user', will try loading '/root/.pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'user', will try loading '/root/.config/pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'site', will try loading '/usr/pip.conf'
```

If not already present, then you can create the pip.conf file at any one of these locations (This is valid for virtual env as well). Ref. https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_config/#cmdoption-user for variant specification.

Then add below sources to pip.conf file:

```
trusted-host = pypi.org
               pypi.python.org
               pypi.org
               pypi.co
               files.pythonhosted.org
               pip.pypa.io
```

Save and start with pip install or download as usual..

To locate cert, install certifi and run below piece of code:

```
[root@localhost ~]# python3 -c "import certifi; print(certifi.where())"
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually comes from a wrong path in `global.cert=old\path\cacert.pem` in pip configuration. To solve this issue, follow the steps below:

1. Use the following command to check `global.cert=path\cacert.pem` in your pip configuration using
   `pip config -v list` command. If this path does not exist, you need to update it.
2. Try to find the right path of your `cacert.pem` file which looks like this in Windows: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\certifi\cacert.pem`.
3. Reset this path using: `pip config set global.cert "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\certifi\cacert.pem"`
4. Check again your pip configuration to confirm that the path was changed (step 1).

The issue can be also solved using Windows variables which might require restarting your computer. But this one does not.

Answer (score -1):

We get this all the time for various 'git' actions.  We have our own CA + intermediary and we don't customize our software installations enough to accomodate that fact.

Our general fix is update your `ca-bundle.crt` with the CA cert pems via either concatenation or replacement.

e.g. `cat my_cert_chain.pem >> $(python -c "import certifi; print(certifi.where())")`

This works great if you have an `/etc/pki/tls/certs` directory, but with python the `python -c "import certifi; print(certifi.where())"` tells you the location of python's ca-bundle.crt file.

Althought it's not a purist python answer, since we're not adding a new file / path, it solves alot of other certificate problems with other software when you understand the underlying issue.

I recommended concatenating in this case as I don't know what else the file is used for vis-a-vis pypi.

Answer (score -1):

1. (security find-certificate -a -p ls /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain &&        security find-certificate -a -p ls /Library/Keychains/System.keychain) > $HOME/.mac-ca-roots
2. export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE="$HOME/.mac-ca-roots"
3. source ~/