# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError

Tags: python, ssl, pip

Trying to install flask, a python library for the web.
I have the error :

`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: path/to/ca-bundle.crt.`

No matter what library I try to install, I come back to the same problem.
It's been doing this to me for the last week when I could "pip install everything" before.

I am on macOS Catalina (10.15), I use Iterm and Pycharm.

By typing: `python --version` in the terminal, I get `Python 3.7.4`. I think I've described the situation well, don't hesitate to ask me questions about my system or anything.

Anyone have an idea to fix this problem?

Thank you in advance,

Paul

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56738345/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-could-not-find-a-suitable)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+EnvironmentError%3A+Could+not+find+a+suitable+TLS+CA+certificate+bundle%2C+invalid+path