# what is the solution to this pip ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle

Tags: django, postgresql, windows, django-rest-framework, pip

So I was trying my hand on a django project that has to do with authentication, on trying to install django-ses for aws email service, I have this error

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt

and since I had installed postgressql 16/pgadmin for database. And now I discovered that it has affected my pip, I can't install any package, the error keeps popping up, please I need solutions to this, since I got a project deadline.

I have tried various suggesions from this links:

[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56738345/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-could-not-find-a-suitable)

[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56738345/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-could-not-find-a-suitable) and various others, none is working, even youtube is not giving a solution.

I need solution, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This needs more information. To your question add as text:  1) Django version 2) Python version and whether you are working in virtualenv.

Comment: asker wrote up their solution [here](https://medium.com/@augustusinyang/resolving-tls-ca-certificate-bundle-issue-in-windows-11-cd32038f7c90). trying to get them to write up an answer post which isn't just a link.